# cannot insert into linked SQL table from an access form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form where I am using VBA code where I defined an STRSQL as **Insert into** 
and applying the **CurrentDb.Execute STRSQL**

It is working fine for local table but when I tried to use it on a linked table, nothing is inserted and I don't get any error message.

Note that if I convert the linked table to local, inserting works fine also.

I have a primary key in my linked table and I am able to fill it manually.

I also noticed that most of my data type in the linked table are as Text and not as Date as defined on SQL server.

The SQL user that I used have writing permissions to the table.

Answer (score 0):

The CurrentDb is a DAO object referencing the current local database. You need to connect the SQL Server tables via DAO ODBC connection to use the `db.Execute` command.

Alternatively, you can create an append stored query interacting with linked tables and call it with `DoCmd.OpenQuery` or use your append query VBA string with `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Comment: I mention how in my answer: 1) create a new append query object scripted like your VBA string (minus variables and outside quotes), save the query, and call it in VBA `DoCmd.OpenQuery qryname` or 2) run the command `DoCmd.RunSQL strsql` in VBA. You may need to Set Warnings False to avoid append query warning. For more info, Google the commands.